# Updating Blob Name

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm having an issue Updating a blobs name - I have done this no problem before but in this case I'm storing the blob in IndexedDB and based on certain conditions (save/saveas) it gets a name from Google Drive or you can add a new name.

Dom JS File

```
      //Convert Text to Blob
  let file = text;

  fileName = "NewFileName";

  let metadata = {
    name: fileName, // Filename
    mimeType: "application/pdf", // mimeType at Google Drive
  };

  let form = new FormData();
  form.append(
    "metadata",
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: "application/json" })
  );
  form.append("file", file);

  let textBlob = new Blob([file], {
    'type': 'application/pdf',
  });
```

Then My ServiceWorker Receives it and renames it then uploads it to google Drive

```
    let blobPDF = request.result.text;

    let blob = new Blob([blobPDF], {
    type: "application/pdf"
    });
    let newBlob = new FormData();

    console.log("Blob Name : " + saveas)
    //Set New Name
    newBlob.append("blob", blob, saveas);

    fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken }),
        body: blob  // Also tried newBlob var -> Got not a blob error
      }
    )
```

if I use the var newBlob it says it's not a blob and errors - then changed to "file" it still doesn't set name

Comment: what do you get for  console.log("Blob Name : " + saveas)

Comment: The Correct Name that it's supposed to Save as

Comment: And the fetch request, have you verified that correct data is being sent? if yes then it's less of a JS issue and more of a googleapi issue

Comment: I can see the response after it's sent - gets a 200 and I can't find enough info to confirm metadata. Is there a way to view the fetch data being sent? (Dumb question prob)

Comment: `Network` tab in developer console can be used to view and debug requests/responses as it logs all requests ajax, images, documents, websockets everything

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. I'm also curious if it's an indexedDB issue. They wanted Blob stored - before i had text store and THEN converted it to Blob and it uploaded with correct name and content.

Comment: You can console.log fetched data from indexedDB to verify whether it's returned correctly or not. If it's correct then verify that whether fetch is sending correctly or not and so on. You get the point :)

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Ah I see it's not including the metadata when sending it to the google drive

Comment: Glad that you found it out quickly (y)

Comment: Thanks! Quick fix once figured it out - and now I know how to check my fetches which is great

Answer (score 1):

One obvious mistake is that you're sending the `blob` itself as the body of your `fetch` request, not the `newBlob` form data object with the filename.

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken }),
  body: newBlob
//        ^^^^
})
```

If that doesn't help, I'd try [creating a `File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) instead of a `Blob`:

```
let blob = new File([blobPDF], saveas, {
  type: "application/pdf"
});
```

Comment: FormData.append's third param should be enough, no need for a File here whose name would be overriden by that third param anyway.

Comment: I had that before and it would cause an error saying it was not a Blob since a New FormData() - I also tried the file instead of a blob and the name didn't get set. I essentially had to create a new blob with the content of the blob and then the metadata got sent correctly

Comment: @matt What exactly was the error message and where was it thrown?

Comment: @Bergi I tried multiple things but when I had newBlob in it said the object was not a blob, when I tried creating a file instead of blob it did not create the name - so I tried sending the "blob" var and no dice either , was just throwing spaghetti at the wall